# Ask for password on first login PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, passwords

I have a web app where currently it works with email addresses and passwords so you can email out a token for people to click and setup their password. This is working fine.

Im adding an option for PIN users who do not have email accounts and I want to be able to let them set their password up on first login. When the user is setup currently the database password field is unpopulated (this could be changed if required)

I'm a little stuck as to how to proceed with this, currently my login view looks like this:

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">        
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <form class="form-center" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('account/login_submit'); ?>" role="form">
                    <h2 class="">Login</h2>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input style="margin: 0px 0px;" type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address/PIN"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo $domain; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="login" type="submit" value="Go"/>
                    <input class="btn btn-warning" name="forgot" type="submit" value="Forgot Password"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

What I think is the best way forward is to capture if someone logs in with a PIN and doesnt have a password set in the database and forward them to a page to setup their password.

This is where this question (in my opinion) gets a little iffy as Im a bit unsure what Im asking.

Currently the login submit button gets called if you press the forgot password and has the below code

```
public function login_submit()
    { 
        if ($this->input->post('forgot')!==FALSE) 
        {
            try {
                $email  = $this->input->post('email').EMAIL_DOMAIN;

                $this->forgot($email);
            } catch (UserException $ex) {
                $this->alert('Incorrect email', $ex->getMessage(), 'danger');
                header('Location: '.site_url('account/login'));
                return;
            }
        }
```

Should I just add another condition in here that if the forgot button was pressed and the pin was entered that we don't email but redirect to a change password page? something like this? [changing password in php/codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071885/changing-password-in-php-codeigniter)

Or is there a better way of doing the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue

> Currently the login submit button gets called if you press the forgot password and has the below code

You have two button with type "submit"

```
 <input class="btn btn-primary" name="login" type="submit" value="Go"/>
 <input class="btn btn-warning" name="forgot" type="submit" value="Forgot Password"/>
```

Make Forgot Password button to a tag like `<a href="controller/action">Forgot Password</a>`

and do Forgot Password thing there in new page with different form action.

And for

> Ask for password on first login

Create a column for a flag as last login in login table with default value null and then check in you login action if last_login == null then redirect it to change password screen. And after login success update last login field by current date.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a sensible way forward.